# Finding a string inside a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a part of str1 inside str2 (two strings). Currently I have a working program however it's not exactly working correctly or using the correct logic in my opinion.

```
public static void main(String[] params) {
    String str1 = "blis";
    String str2 = "grisdisbliszis";
    //String str2 = "adasdsfgsdfdcx";
    System.out.println(isCommonSubstring(str1, str2));
}

public static boolean isCommonSubstring(String str1, String str2) {

    char char1, char2;
    boolean match = true;
    String check = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        char1 = str1.charAt(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
            char2 = str2.charAt(j);
            if(char1 == char2) {
                check += char1;
                System.out.println("Matched!: "+str1.charAt(i)+"[Char "+i+"] <==> " // DEBUG
                    +str2.charAt(j)+"[Char "+j+"]");                                // DEBUG
                break; // Break because we've found our first match and we need to check others
            }
        }
    }
        System.out.println(check+" || "+str1);
        if(check.equals(str1)) match = true;
            else match = false;

    return match;
}
```

This may work but if I turn these two strings around it no longer works.

How can I improve the logic of finding a match? I tried to possibly use substring() somehow however I'm not sure how to fit it inside.

The solution I'm thinking of is possibly making if statements to compare lengths and make str2 the longer length so it's always longer and does not cause errors. But is this a decent solution?

I can only use length, substring and charAt.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using either the built-in String function or a utility like StringUtils?

Comment: Try looking up knuth morris pratt algorithm more info can be found here https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960227.html

Comment: You should be clear if you cannot use the existing Java String API or not. Is this homework?

Comment: Forgot to mention I cannot use anything other than length, substring and charAt. Sorry.

Comment: Are you actually trying to find a common substring? If so, the name `isSubstring` is misleading, because it leads the readers to think your method is checking if str1 is a substring of str2.

Comment: Edit your question than and put it in the requierements

Comment: "This may work but if I turn these two strings around it no longer works." You need to specify what "may work" and "no longer works" mean. Surely it does or it doesn't; if it doesn't, in what way does it not?

Comment: @AndyTurner If str1 is longer than str2 the process does not work anymore.

Comment: @Xylus what does "does not work" mean? Crashes? Returns the wrong value?

Comment: @Xylus, if your requirement is to find any match of str1 or str2 in the other, then the length of the Strings is an important early logic decision. Otherwise, if the requirements are that str1 is or is not in str2, then if str1 is larger than str2 you have an early return.

Comment: If that's your only problem why not check first which is longer and then loop on that...

Comment: Returns the wrong value. For example if str2 is `blis` and str1 is `gisdisbliszis` then the `check` value will be `isisblisis`

Comment: @PetterFriberg Yes but how exactly would I do that? If str2 is longer than str1 I can do what I do now but what if it's the other way around? I should somehow swap the strings?

Comment: @Xylus and what should it be? You need to describe the expected behaviour, your question isn't actually very clear right now. (See RealSkeptic's comment)

Comment: Use a temporary variable for example, String iAmTheLongOne = .... the let everybody loop around the LongOne

Comment: @AndyTurner str1 is `blis` and str2 is `grisdisbliszis`. I then compare the chars and it would find `blis` inside `grisdisbliszis` however if I turn these strings around it will instead find `isisblisis` instead of `blis` inside `grisdisbliszis`

Comment: @Xylus, remember that a parameter can be stored in a local. `String longest = str1;`

Comment: @Xylus Take a look at my solution. It is probably what your school wants.

Comment: @Xylus don't give up one your code you are close... just check the comments

Comment: @PetterFriberg Well from what you said I added a `str3` local to `isCommonSubstring` and replaced `str2` operations to `str3` operations in the `for loop` I then added two variables to check the length of `str1` and `str2` and also added an if statement `if(str1Length < str2Length) str3 = str2;` and an `else str3 = str1;` it works both ways now but not sure if it's doing it right. From what I understood = is just for alias it doesn't actually replace the strings, or something along those lines. Basically it works, but I don't know if it's because of correct logic.

Comment: And another problem comes up now. Whenever I make `str1 = "blisis"` and `str2 = "andistidblisman"` it will return true even though `blisis` is nowhere. I'm not sure if this is even possible?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Huh? I have `check += char1;` right before the break.

Comment: sorry, was to quick to check code... we need a way to reset... ; )

Comment: Yassin down there did it so simply but I don't know how to think of it like that by myself.

Comment: Xylus I have spent some time on your code, to solve it you need to pass the char1 inside of the inner loop and do something like this char1 = str1.charAt(i+j); since you want to check that the char follows one after the  other... and then after the inner loop check if equals and break;...

Comment: As you will see it will be very close to Yassin' answer he just optimize the length in the outer loop as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm here would be the following :

1. Use a main loop that will stop either when the word is found, or when we've reached his length minus the length of the second string. (For example : If str1 has a length of 6 and str2 a length of 4, we know str2 does not begin at index 3 for example).
2. Use a second loop to check if the indexes of str2 fit somehow in str1. We check each index, one after the other inside the inner. If one of them doesn't correspond to the looped indexes of the main loop, we break from the inner loop and add one to the index of the main loop.
3. If the inner loop finished succesfully, we know that the word is found.

---

Here is a short solution possible using only `charAt()` and `lenght()`:

```
    static boolean isCommonSubstring (String one, String two) {
        if (one.length() < two.length()){
            String tmp = one;
            one = two;
            two = tmp;
        }
        MAIN :
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= one.length()-two.length() ; i++){
            for (int j = 0 ; j < two.length() ; j++){
                if ((one.charAt(i+j) != two.charAt(j))) continue MAIN;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe we help more if we do not provide own code, but help figuring out how to do it themself...., i will not down vote since you are correct

Comment: You're right Petter. That is the reason why I added the explanation.

Comment: Provide some notion to xylus what he need to do to make his code work, and you will get my upvote (specially since he does not wan't to be forced to pass first the longest and then the shortes... hence you have same result as xylus if you invert one and two

Comment: Whats does your metod return if String one = "blis" and String two = "grisdisbliszis"? see comments under question to understand..

Comment: Just invert the strings.. You can not have a string containing a greater string...

Comment: Exactly... his metod needs to invert the strings... thats why its not called contains..., no, still false he wants true

Comment: No he wants true you need temp variable... sorry for all comments but this has become a mission for me.. : )

Comment: You earned it, check out last comments under the question to understand why,..., thanks

Comment: Thank you I learned about ternary operator from your example :)

Answer (score 1):

`String.contains()` is what you are looking for.

[Simple tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm)

Unless you have requirements not to use builtin functions, dont reinvent the wheel.

Example from tutorial link above:

```
String str1 = "tutorials point", str2 = "http://";

   CharSequence cs1 = "int";

   // string contains the specified sequence of char values
   boolean retval = str1.contains(cs1);
   System.out.println("Method returns : " + retval);

   // string does not contain the specified sequence of char value
   retval = str2.contains("_");   
   System.out.println("Methods returns: " + retval);
   }
```

If you want case insensitive:

```
str1.toLowerCase.contains(str2.toLowerCase());
```

**EDIT**
turns out OP cannot use `builtin` functions. Will leave the answer here just in case any one else comes here who doesn't want to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: I removed my upvote, seems like OP cannot use built in functions, so your solution (however correct) will not be helpful.

Comment: @Ceelos. Yeah thats understandable. But someone else downvoted and just want to know if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> I can only use length, substring and charAt

Since you can only use those methods. This is what you can do:

```
//Self-defined method to check whether sub exist in str
public static boolean contains(String str, String sub){
    if(sub.length() > str.length())
        return false;    

    for(int x=0; x<= str.length() - sub.length(); x++)
        if(str.substring(x, sub.length()+x).equals(sub))                
            return true;                            
    return false;
}
```

---

**EXPLANATION:**

The loop will the check whether `sub` exist in `str` in the following approach:

```
apple (Compare "app" with "ple"  ==> does not match);
^^^    
apple (Compare "ppl" with "ple"  ==> does not match);
 ^^^    
apple (Compare "ple" with "ple"  ==> match, return true);
  ^^^
```

**TESTING:**

```
String a = "apple";
String b = "ple";   
System.out.println(a + " contains " + b + ": " + contains(a, b));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
apple contains ple: true
```

Comment: Note xylus does not like to first pass the longest and then the shortest... this is his problem... check comments...

Comment: @PetterFriberg If that is the case, he can simply swap the arguments "str" and "sub". Actually it is not even a problem at all. By improvising on my codes a little, str1 can be longer than str2 and vice versa.

Comment: Well if you read the comments on the question you will found out what the problem was.. I will move on have fun...